# Blend Mode Alpha Clip Doesn't Show in Eevee Render

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency

I'm following a Ducky3D tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlizedfuIN4&list=PL70822sOht70HP8t3TPBeHy1jny9nuFrr&index=65&t=342s

The alpha clip in the material settings is supposed to show an array of see through planes. Without the alpha clip, it's not see through. How do I get the alpha clip to render?

No matter what the alpha clip won't show in an Eevee render. I don't want to use Cycles because it looks weird.

Viewport display Vs Eevee below

Viewport Display:
[image]

Eevee Render:
[image]

Cycles Render:
[image]

Comment: Those black lines in cycles are probably caused by not having enough transparent bounces. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects/27719#27719 Or it could also be Z-fighting. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71025/intersecting-transparent-object-causing-artifacts-in-cycles

Comment: So the answer was actually a lot less complicated than I thought. I had an overlapping plane in my scene. Your 2nd link mentioned that overlapping planes will cause this. Thank you!